# Cuantos parametros se pueden usar al redirecionar en Django

Tags: django, redirección, parametros

Ejemplo

```
return redirect(url, parametro1, parametro2, parametro?)
```

Cuantos parámetros se pueden pasar a la url a redireccionar.